# need help: How to get a totally new instance of a wasm module without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, rust, webassembly

My original requirement was that: I have a compiled wasm module writing by rust, and I used lasy_static! internally to store some state, and I hope that at some point I can recompile this wasm module and clear all data and memory without refreshing the page. For example, when a user has completed a process and wants to start again.

But at present, I found that although webpack already supports importing wasm modules through import, but in the case of the browser not refreshing, I always have only one wasm instance, and even I have changed the compiled code, but it still fails to reach My appeal, so come here for help, here are some of my attempts:

This is the rust code for a simple wasm module:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;
extern crate wasm_bindgen;
extern crate serde_json;

use web_sys;

use std::{sync::Mutex};
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use std::sync::PoisonError;
use std::panic;

pub struct CurrentStatus {
  pub index: i32,
}

impl CurrentStatus {
  fn new() -> Self {
    CurrentStatus {
      index: 1,
    }
  }
  fn get_index(&mut self) -> i32 {
    self.index.clone()
  }

  fn add_index(&mut self) {
    self.index += 1;
  }
}

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref FOO: Mutex<CurrentStatus> = Mutex::new(CurrentStatus::new());
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn add_index() {
  FOO.lock().unwrap_or_else(PoisonError::into_inner).add_index();
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn get_index() -> i32 {
  let mut foo = FOO.lock().unwrap_or_else(PoisonError::into_inner);
  return foo.get_index();
}
```

Then I use wasm-pack to pack it, and then call it through js:

```
const js = import("../pkg/hello_wasm.js");
js.then(js => {
  js.add_index();
  console.log(js.get_index());
});

setTimeout(() => {
  const js = import("../pkg/hello_wasm.js")
  js.then(js => {
    js.add_index();
    console.log(js.get_index());
    js.add_index();
  });
}, 2000);
```

Of course, the default code returns the same instance, so I try to modify the compiled code of webpack:

The original webpack compiled code looks like this (a key part is here, interested friends can also try it for themselves):

```
wasmModules.forEach(function(wasmModuleId) {
/******/     var installedWasmModuleData = installedWasmModules[wasmModuleId];
/******/
/******/     // a Promise means "currently loading" or "already loaded".
/******/     if(installedWasmModuleData)
/******/      promises.push(installedWasmModuleData);
/******/     else {
/******/      var importObject = wasmImportObjects[wasmModuleId]();
/******/      var req = fetch(__webpack_require__.p + "" + {"2":"4f77fe13132b31e5eb67"}[wasmModuleId] + ".module.wasm");
/******/      var promise;
/******/      if(importObject instanceof Promise && typeof WebAssembly.compileStreaming === 'function') {
/******/       promise = Promise.all([WebAssembly.compileStreaming(req), importObject]).then(function(items) {
/******/        return WebAssembly.instantiate(items[0], items[1]);
/******/       });
/******/      } else if(typeof WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming === 'function') {
/******/       promise = WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(req, importObject);
/******/      } else {
/******/       var bytesPromise = req.then(function(x) { return x.arrayBuffer(); });
/******/       promise = bytesPromise.then(function(bytes) {
/******/        return WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, importObject);
/******/       });
/******/      }
/******/      promises.push(installedWasmModules[wasmModuleId] = promise.then(function(res) {
/******/       return __webpack_require__.w[wasmModuleId] = (res.instance || res).exports;
/******/      }));
/******/     }
/******/    });
/******/    return Promise.all(promises);
```

I removed the cache here and made it re-pull and call instantiate every time (also tried using compileStreaming):

```
/******/   var wasmModules = {"1":[2]}[chunkId] || [];
/******/
/******/    wasmModules.forEach(function(wasmModuleId) {
/******/     var installedWasmModuleData = installedWasmModules[wasmModuleId];
/******/
              __webpack_require__.w[wasmModuleId] = void 0;

              console.log('__webpack_require__.w[wasmModuleId]:', __webpack_require__.w[wasmModuleId]);

/******/     // a Promise means "currently loading" or "already loaded".
/******/     if(installedWasmModuleData)
/******/      promises.push(installedWasmModuleData);
/******/     else {
/******/      var importObject = wasmImportObjects[wasmModuleId]();
/******/      var req = fetch(__webpack_require__.p + "" + {"2":"4f77fe13132b31e5eb67"}[wasmModuleId] + ".module.wasm");
/******/      var promise;
/******/      if(importObject instanceof Promise && typeof WebAssembly.compileStreaming === 'function') {
/******/       promise = Promise.all([WebAssembly.compileStreaming(req), importObject]).then(function(items) {
/******/        return WebAssembly.instantiate(items[0], items[1]);
/******/       });
/******/      } else if(typeof WebAssembly.compileStreaming === 'function') {
/******/       promise = WebAssembly.compileStreaming(req, importObject);
/******/      } else {
/******/       var bytesPromise = req.then(function(x) { return x.arrayBuffer(); });
/******/       promise = bytesPromise.then(function(bytes) {
/******/        return WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, importObject);
/******/       });
/******/      }
/******/      promises.push(promise.then(function(res) { // change here!
                  return WebAssembly.instantiate(res, importObject).then((instance) => {
                    return __webpack_require__.w[wasmModuleId] = instance.exports;
                  })
// /******/      return __webpack_require__.w[wasmModuleId] = (res.instance || res).exports;
/******/      }));
/******/     }
/******/    });
/******/    return Promise.all(promises);
```

I want it to output the same result twice, which shows that I successfully re-initialized the wasm module.

but the output:

```
2
3
```

Obviously, there is no re-initialization of a wasm instance, which is very disturbing to me. I don't know how to do it to get a new instance ..

and I also create a mini-repo: https://github.com/aircloud/wasm-single-test

can run the demo by the command showed.

Comment: Why do this instead of changing the wasm module to act as a factory capable of returning multiple instances? Generally, module systems assume you want to deduplicate whenever possible, so working around that will be difficult.

Comment: @PitaJ The reason I can't do this here is that I don't know how many instances need to be created. And wasm internally stores information through global variables because it is inconvenient to manage the state entirely by JS. In addition, I also want to isolate errors between different instances. so I need to create a totally new wasm instance